# Edit 'User License' field for a user using SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, soap, user

I was thinking 'userType' is the attribute for the field 'User License' but it isn't.

Does someone know the correct attribute to set using SOAP API for 'User License' field?

I also want to know the value to set for each choice in the dropdown:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User type is just an indicator about user type such as Community User, Standard User, Chatter User etc.

There is a Userlicense object to store all the user licenses available in the org. While using SOAP API's, first you will have to query this object and get the related ID.

Relationship between user and license is via Profiles

> User -> Profile -> Userlicense

So if you want to update the User license, you will have to follow below approach

1. Query license ID
2. Query available profileID for the license
3. Update user with that profileID